# How to solve "stateful problems" in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I'm new to clojure and I'm having trouble to understand some concepts, specially pure functions and immutability.

One thing that I still can't comprehend is how you solve a problem like this in clojure:

A simple console application with a  login method, where the user can't try to login more than 3 times in a 1 minute interval.

In C# for example I could add the UserId and a timestamp to a collection every time the user tries to login, then I would check if there has been more 3 than attempts in the last minute.

How would I do that in Clojure considering that I can't alter my collection ?

This is not a pratical question (although some code examples would be welcomed), I want to understand how you approach a problem like this.

Comment: I think Carcigenicate has a great answer to your specific question. For more generally understanding Clojure program design I recommend checking out "Bottom Up vs Top Down Design in Clojure - Mark Bastian" on youtube.

Comment: Thanks, I wil defintenly take a look. I've checked a couple of resources but none of them had the answer to what I'm asking.

Comment: To be able to give a more relevant answer, I think I would need a more concrete example that shows how data is being used. If you're dealing with async code, you may need to use an `atom` as I showed at the bottom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't alter objects in most cases, you create new versions of the old objects:

```
(loop [attempt-dates []]
  (if (login-is-correct)
    (login)
    (recur (conj attempt-dates (current-date-stamp)))))
```

In this case I'm using `loop`. Whatever I give to `recur` will be passed to the next iteration of `loop`. I'm creating a new list that contains the new stamp when I write `(conj attempt-dates (current-date-stamp))`, then that new list is passed to the next iteration of `loop`.

This is how it's done in most cases. Instead of thinking about altering the object, think about creating a transformed copy of the object and passing the copy along.

If you really truly do need mutable state though, you can use a mutable `atom` to hold an immutable state:

```
(def mut-state (atom []))

(swap! mut-state conj 1)

(println @mut-state)  ; Prints [1]
```

`[]` is still immutable here, the new version is just replacing the old version in the mutable `atom` container.

Unless you're needing to communicate with UI callbacks or something similar though, you usually don't actually need mutability. Practice using `loop`/`recur` and `reduce` instead.

Comment: Sorry for deleting the comment. At first I thought I comprehended your example but I didn`t. After giving it some thouth I finally did. I had the wrong ideia that your code would be like an endpoint, and the  "attempt-dates" would be empty at every new request from the user.

Comment: @M.Arkk Oh, no. `attempt-dates` carries between each iteration within one call to `loop`. If you were taking requests inside of the `loop`, then this will work. If you're asynchronously taking requests elsewhere, I'd probably use an `atom`.